# How to raise version of oraclize-api installed via Truffle

Tags: truffle, oracles

I'm using local instance of Oraclize API, to make `truffle compile` work. I've installed it by

```
truffle install oraclize-api
```

but for now, I'm getting following error

> if (oraclize_randomDS_args[queryId] == keccak256(commitmentSlice1,
>   sessionPubkeyHash)){ //unonce, nbytes and sessionKeyHash match
>                                                 ^--------------------------------------------^

Looks like I'm getting it because version of usingOraclize is ^0.4.18, and I use ^0.4.24 for my project. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that Truffle installs contracts from the EthPM. We can found `oraclize-api` at https://www.ethpm.com/registry/packages/37, and see that there is only single version. It's pretty outdated already. I don't see how to update it by myself in EthPM repo (probably that only way is to duplicate package), and for now I think the best option is to grab actual version from the repo (https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api) and just put it into the project.